# unable to integrate razorpay in angular js templates

Tags: angularjs, razorpay

I am trying to integrate [razorpay](https://docs.razorpay.com/docs/checkout-form) in my angualar project

here is the code

```
<form action="/purchase" method="POST">
<!-- Note that the amount is in paise = 50 INR -->
<script
src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"
data-key="<YOUR_KEY_ID>"
data-amount="5000" 
data-name="Merchant Name"
data-description="Purchase Description"
data-image="https://your-awesome-site.com/your_logo.jpg"
data-prefill.name="Harshil Mathur"
data-prefill.email="support@razorpay.com"
data-theme.color="#F37254"
></script>
<input type="hidden" value="Hidden Element" name="hidden">
</form>
```

But in angular js is not executing this code
Please help me

Answer (score 13):

If you are already using angular, I'd advice you to try our [manual checkout](https://docs.razorpay.com/docs/checkout-form#manual-checkout) instead. The code would look something like:

```
app.controller('PaymentsCtrl', [
  '$scope',
  function ($scope) {
    $scope.options = {
      'key': '<Your-Key-Here>',
      // Insert the amount here, dynamically, even
      'amount': '50000',
      'name': '',
      'description': 'Pay for Order #2323',
      'image': '',
      'handler': function (transaction) {
        $scope.transactionHandler(transaction);
      },
      'prefill': {
        'name': '',
        'email': '',
        'contact': ''
      }
    };
    $scope.btnClick = function () {
      var rzp1 = new Razorpay($scope.options);
      rzp1.open();
    };
}]);
```

And in your template:

```
<button ng-click="btnClick">Click to Pay</button>
```

Disclaimer: I work at Razorpay.

Comment: hay hi how do you included the checkout.js file in your angular application?  i am not able to create Razorpay() object throwing me an error.

Comment: Just make sure that the checkout.js script is included before you run this code. Load it from `https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js`

Comment: @AbhayRana how can i capture failed transactions? Handler only triggers successful transactions isnt it?

Comment: You can't capture failed transactions. Only authorized transactions can be captured. We provide a webhook for failed transactions and a handler for `modal.ondismiss`. See https://docs.razorpay.com/v1/page/webhooks and https://docs.razorpay.com/docs/checkout-form#checkout-fields

Comment: where does it redirects on successful transactions ? in my case it its redirecting to `file://purchase`

Comment: @NileshDeokar The redirect happens if you are using automatic-checkout (The one with the script tag inside a form tag, and we automatically submit the form on transaction completion). If you want more control, please use manual checkout and be sure to define a handler function in the config.

Answer (score 3):

If you face any problem to load .js externally, You can use $.getScript(); function for loading .js files.

```
  $scope.options = {

          'key': 'rzp_test_1DP5mmOlF5G5ag',
          'amount': 100,
          'name': '',
          'description': 'Pay for Order #2323',
          'image': '',
          'handler': function (transaction) {
            $scope.transactionHandler(transaction);
          },
          'prefill': {
            'name': '',
            'email': '',
            'contact': ''
          },
          theme:{
            color: '#3399FF'
          }
    };

  $scope.pay = function(){

          $.getScript('https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js', function() {
            var rzp1 = new Razorpay($scope.options);
          rzp1.open();

          });


   };
```